# Overloading << operator for printing out custom exception

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find out how to be able to write something like this:

```
try{
    throw MyCustomException;
}
catch(const MyCustomException &e){
cout<< e;
}
```

But how to define the `overloaded operator <<` for this purpose ?

the custom exception class:

```
class MyCustomException{

public:

MyCustomException(const int& x) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << x; 

    msg_ = "Invalid index [" + ss.str() + "]";
}

string getMessage() const {
    return (msg_);
}
private:
    string msg_;
};
```

Comment: IMO just do `cout << e.getMessage()`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sry, my mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, I believe the correct solution is to **follow standard convention** and make `MyCustomException` derive from `std::exception`. Then, you would implement the `what()` virtual member function to return a message, and you could eventually insert that string into the standard output through `operator <<`.

This is how your exception class would look like:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::string;
using std::stringstream;

class MyCustomException : public std::exception
{
public:

    MyCustomException(const int& x) {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << x;
        msg_ = "Invalid index [" + ss.str() + "]";
    }

    virtual const char* what() const noexcept {
        return (msg_.c_str());
    }

private:

    string msg_;
};
```

And here is how you would use it:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw MyCustomException(42);
    }
    catch(const MyCustomException &e)
    {
        cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Finally, a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/4yc7Hy%243646).